# Oracle SQL: Column not allowed

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE AIRLINE (
    airline_code        NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    airline_name        VARCHAR(29) NOT NULL,
    airline_address1    VARCHAR(29) NOT NULL,
    airline_address2    VARCHAR(29),
    airline_postcode    VARCHAR(29),
    airline_city        VARCHAR(29) NOT NULL,
    airline_country     VARCHAR(29) NOT NULL
);
```

And when I insert this Insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO AIRLINE (airline_code, airline_name, airline_address1, airline_address2, airline_postcode, airline_city, airline_country)
VALUES ("BA07", "British Airways PLC", "Waterside", "PO Box 365, Harmondsworth", "UB7 0GB", "London", "United Kingdom");
```

I get an error pointing to United Kingdom saying 'column not allowed here', as far as I'm aware there's the same number of columns as there is data being inserted into the table.

Comment: Also, there is a `datatype` mismatch for `airline_code`, you cannot use `NUMBER` to store `'BA07'`. See my answer.

Comment: If in doubt, read the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218 and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double quotes are usually used to object names (e.g. column name "First name"). That is part of SQL-92 standard.

In ANSI SQL, double quotes quote object names (e.g. tables) which allows them to contain characters not otherwise permitted, or be the same as reserved words (Avoid this, really).

Single quotes are for strings.

```
INSERT INTO AIRLINE (airline_code, airline_name, airline_address1, 
airline_address2, airline_postcode, airline_city, airline_country)
VALUES ('BA07', 'British Airways PLC', 'Waterside', 'PO Box 365, 
Harmondsworth', 'UB7 0GB', 'London', 'United Kingdom');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes arround the strings not double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

> airline_code        NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
>
> "BA07"

In addition to to the other answers regarding the double-quotation marks, you need to make sure you do not use any single-quotation marks for a **NUMBER** data type, you need to enclose  the values within single-quotation marks only for a **STRING**.

In your case, **column airline_code** is type **NUMBER(4)**. But, the value that you want to **insert** is **alphanumeric**, `'BA07'`. SO, you need to first change the data type of the column to **VARCHAR2(4)**.

```
CREATE TABLE AIRLINE (
    airline_code        VARCHAR2(4) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    airline_name        VARCHAR(29) NOT NULL,
    airline_address1    VARCHAR(29) NOT NULL,
    airline_address2    VARCHAR(29),
    airline_postcode    VARCHAR(29),
    airline_city        VARCHAR(29) NOT NULL,
    airline_country     VARCHAR(29) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO AIRLINE (airline_code, airline_name, airline_address1, 
airline_address2, airline_postcode, airline_city, airline_country)
VALUES ('BA07', 'British Airways PLC', 'Waterside', 'PO Box 365, 
Harmondsworth', 'UB7 0GB', 'London', 'United Kingdom');
```